# Shift Images when fig.align is not working

Tags: r-markdown, pagedown

I have a radar chart. For some reason, it's not aligned to the page.

The caption is positioned correctly, but I am unable to move the figure to the "left" so that it's not awkwardly placed to the side of the page. If it's of any concern, I am using pagedown library to render PDFs. However, the HTML version has the same issue.

[image: Radar Chart]